Find $u_\varepsilon\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ satisfying $u_\varepsilon'\overset{\mathcal D'}{=}\frac1{x+i\varepsilon}$

Find $u_\varepsilon\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ satisfying $u_\varepsilon'\overset{\mathcal D'}{=}\frac1{x+i\varepsilon}$.

If we assume $u$ as a common function, we have $u_\varepsilon=\log(x+i\varepsilon)$. But there is some problem when $x=0$. So, maybe I should change the definition of $\log$ in this problem? Or can we use some definition like principle value to fix it?

Do you know how is the derivative of a distribution defined?

@SineoftheTime, yes, we have $\langle u',\varphi\rangle=-\langle u,\varphi'\rangle$. The above content is just considering from intuitive.

@SineoftheTime, and indeed it may be some non-regular distribution.

Is anything said about the sign of $\epsilon$? Often one only takes $\epsilon>0.$

@md2perpe It isn't mentioned in this exercise, but I think we have $\varepsilon\neq0$. If $\varepsilon<0$, just consider $\frac1{x-i\epsilon}$. And... yes, I think we can only consider the case of $\varepsilon>0$.

Let us consider the case $\epsilon>0.$
We want to find $u_\epsilon \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R)$ such that
$$
u_\epsilon' 
= \frac{1}{x+i\epsilon} 
= \frac{x-i\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}
= \frac{x}{x^2+\epsilon^2} -i\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}
.
$$
Both terms are ordinary continuous functions, so we can just take antiderivatives:
$$
u_\epsilon = \ln\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2} - i\arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon} + C,
$$
where $C$ is some constant.
But here we can actually recognize the complex logarithm:
$$
u_\epsilon = \log(\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2} e^{-i\arctan\frac{x}{\epsilon}}) + C
= \log(x+i\epsilon) + C.
$$
